# Opensource dropbox-type software?

Tags: linux, cloud, dropbox, vps

Opensource dropbox-type software?

Ive got a VPS and I want to use it for cloud storage. Is there any opensource software to sync  folders to a server in this way?

Has to run on Linux.

Comment: http://alternativeto.net/software/dropbox/?license=opensource or http://alternativeto.net/software/sugarsync/?license=opensource

Comment: Cheers, may look into ownCloud. Looks a bit incomplete though...

Comment: What's the difference between "cloud storage" and "remote backup"?  A single server does not make a cloud.

Answer (score 12):

Have a look at the following.

- [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/)
- [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/)
- [FTPBox](http://ftpbox.org/)
- [Syncany](http://www.syncany.org/)

Based on ghoti's comment.

The difference between cloud storage and remote backup is mainly buzzword, the number of remote hosts your backup is stored on and the easy of synchorinisation / use .

Other remote backup solutions that may suit your need include

- [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) also see auto remote backup [guide](http://www.kutukupret.com/2009/08/30/auto-remote-backup-with-unison/)
- [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) also see the following [guide](http://fak3r.com/2009/09/14/howto-build-your-own-open-source-dropbox-clone/) using ssh, rsync and lsyncd
- cron,ssh and version control system of your choice (git,sunbverstion,etc) (cron job that runs commit command at a given interval, use postcommit hooks on the server to checkout additional copies in other to use more than one host)

Comment: You can try ownCloud easily in your computer with http://bitnami.org/stack/owncloud

Comment: Besides ownCloud, there are two other relevant solutions: Seafile and Pydio